# Visual Leak Detector: File and line number not available

Tags: visual-leak-detector

```
Visual Leak Detector: WARNING! There are memory leaks!

---------- 1 block (#3791210) consuming 24 bytes ----------

  0x1000234A (File and line number not available): Visualleakdetector
  0x102095D6 (File and line number not available): malloc_dbg
  0x102094B9 (File and line number not available): malloc_dbg
  0x10209409 (File and line number not available): malloc
```

The stack goes on but there are no files displayed. What can be the reason?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: It is a debug build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine that you don't have the debug symbols for the program you're analysing (pdb files).
Is this a program you have the source code for? If so, I'd suggest checking you have your project set to generate debug symbols, rebuilding locally, and rerunning the program.

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem. Now it is working fine. Thank you.