# Why won't Visual Leak Detector report file and line number for some stack frames?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-leak-detector

In my Visual Leak Detector output, some (not all) of the frames from my own code comes up with "file and line number not available":

```
0x000000000079B4E8 (File and line number not available): mymodule.dll!namespace1::Class1::Impl::Impl + 0x88 bytes
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13723313/385094) suggests that I might be missing my PDB files, but I set the environment variable `DBGHELP_DBGOUT` per [this thread](https://vld.codeplex.com/discussions/264477) and it is reported that the PDB files are correctly resolved:

```
DBGHELP: mymodule - private symbols & lines 
         F:\Code\MyCompany\MyProduct\Debug\x64\mymodule.pdb
```

So why won't Visual Leak Detector give me file and line numbers for some frames?

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I copied the pdb file(s) but still no file or line number available. In my case I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that I have a mem leak in a DLL and I'm running a test application to call the DLL. Not sure about that because in the end I gave up using VLD (for this case).